# Export multiple DIVs to single pdf

Tags: javascript, html, client, pdf-generation

I have page which shows number of tables within a DIV. Those tables have colspan and other attributes. I want to export the whole DIV in a pdf. I was able to do that by using html2pdf library. But it has scaling issues if the data is big and creates more than 17-18 pages, which is known issue of html2pdf library. To resolve that I wanted to break that parent div into two and combine both but that is also not possible. There are libraries which combine pdfs at nodeJS server side. Can someone help me on how to send whole html(containing div and tables) to node(server side) and then create PDF and Save it? Any other solution will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a button for downloading the site in pdf like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #print_btn{
                cursor:pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="print_btn">Download PDF</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                document.getElementById('print_btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    if(window.print){
                        window.print();
                    }
                })
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And with the css `@media only print{}` rule you can control which elements to hide, or resize.

Comment: This gives error for violating Content Security Policy.                                           
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'. Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I wrote it shorthand just to let you know about this function. I'll edit it to add an event listener.

Comment: Oh Got it. Let me try

Comment: I understand this is one of the solutions. It asks user to either print or Save as pdf instead of automatically saving. As per requirements automatic saving of pdf would be best solution. Also the pdf which is saved is taking page Title as default heading. Some CSS colors not same as on Page.

Comment: Well, the whole task requires tweaking, I imagine.
Unfortunately, the user has to interact with the print or save dialog this way.
If you ever find a faster and better method, do share it.

Comment: As mentioned in my question above, html2pdf library is good one except for large data. I am using dynamic data which might contain more than 20 pages. It has scaling issues.

Comment: I want a solution to merge two pdfs because I can create 2-3 pdfs out of large data and then combine both pdfs.